# Searching by date

Tags: support, questions, search, api

I've had a look through previous questions on Meta and haven't been able to find an answer to this.  Does StackOverflow provide any ability to search by date?

For example, if I wanted to search for all questions tagged Python in the last 3 days, is that possible?  Or all Haskell questions in October?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This has now been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162064/223030).

> For example, if I wanted to search for all questions tagged Python in the last 3 days, is that possible?

```
[python] created:2014-02-22..2014-02-24
```

> Or all Haskell questions in October?

Assuming October *2013*:

```
[haskell] created:2013-10
```

Answer (score 4):

Sort of.

- Do your search
- Then sort results by Newest
- Then jump pages until you're at a range that fits inside your time period.

Comment: I'd like to get this information programatically.  I guess it's possible with this method, just a bit cumbersome.  I actually only want the number of questions, not the content.

Answer (score 1):

The data dump would provide this sort of information (until up to a month ago) pretty easily. It's obviously not an online search though.