# How to search for wiki questions after the removal of the "make community wiki" option

Tags: support, search, community-wiki

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki:1 : Shows all community wiki questions.

How would I be able to search for wiki questions that have been made after the change in October,

[Users can not mark questions wiki anymore, across the network.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192)

<sub>Or at least I think that is when the changed happened (?)</sub>

Comment: Try the data explorer instead?

Comment: Not really what you want, but as a work around you could search for `wiki:1 views:0` (the views removes answers from the results list) and then use the `newest` tab - the results you want are at the top of the list (in terms of pages), but obviously results that you *don't* want will still be returned on later pages.

Comment: @DMA's solution is currently the only in-engine method of doing it through the site. There is no way to mechanically filter the search by any specific date element, although there is a [request formerly tagged ninjas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options) that asks for such functionality. The exact date was October 14th, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Use the aforementioned `wiki:1` plus the `created` param with the `yyyy-mm-dd` format and `..` for range:

```
wiki:1 created:2011-10-14..
```

An example URL version of this would be:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+created%3A2011-10-14..
```

**References**

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching