# Make Questions/Answers with Extreme Votes visible below 10k rep?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

With 10k rep we get access to the [Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/) that show "interesting" activity, presumably to turn users into assistant-moderators.

However, I often find myself looking at the high voted stuff simply because it's usually a really interesting/obscure question or answer. Some examples include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208967/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142251/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987415/).

The [Highest Voted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) tab is kinda useless as it's lifetime votes, not based on last day/week.

So I'm wondering if that tab should get the save 2d/7d/30d filter, or if the High Voted Questions/Answers should otherwise be given to people below 10k rep?

Comment: Related, that may satisfy this in a totally different way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options

Comment: Interesting, we do have this for answers http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/hot

Answer (score 3):

It would form a cycle.  The highest activity questions would simply get more views.

I don't think that we should turn SO into an interesting engine.  Programmers already come here to waste time - to our obvious benefit - but the fact that they come because they are bored suggests that if we give them another outlet for their boredom, we might sap our answers.

Further, it would amplify the subjective question problem, and give people another thing to try and game.  Get your question on the list and it's free rep.

I don't see an upside.