# List questions after a certain date

Tags: support, search

Is there a way of listing only questions posted after a certain date? For instance if I click on the C++ tag, the search box shows `[c++]`. I'd like to edit the search box to have instead something like

```
[c++] after:2012-01-01
```

to get all c++ posts that were added after Jan 1st.

Comment: You can't do this directly, so you might want to turn this into a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the 'Newest' tab on Search Results to see the results of your query in descending order by date.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thx, this works. In addition, if I want unanswered questions, I can have search box `[c++] answers:0` and click on Newest as you describe.  I tried `[c++] answers:0 answers:1` to get posts with either 0 or 1 answers (which I would then sort using Newest tab) but that didn't work.

Comment: @Schollii: The SO search system is a bit weird that way. Tags and operators like `answers:n` are required in results (i.e. AND-search), while only one keyword must match (i.e. OR-search), unless prefixed by a `+`.

Answer (score 2):

[This has now been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162064/223030).

Using your example:

> [Is there a way] to get all c++ posts that were added after Jan 1st[?]

```
[c++] created:2012-01-01..
```

That gives all C++ questions asked after Jan 1<sup>st</sup> 2012. Add another date after the `..` to restrict the search to before that date. For all the search options see the above link.