# Search inside my own answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

When I write an answer, I like to get a particular answer I wrote earlier for reference. But when I go into my activity tab in the profile page, I do not have any way to find out which answer it is. I do not want to favorite all the questions I answered, so it would be a great idea to be able to search through my answers. It will be awesome if it would let me to search for a specific tag or answer I wrote within a specific time-frame.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 27):

You can use the main search box for this, with the search query `user:me is:answer <query>`.

For example, [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+%5Bphp%5D) should return all of your answers tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php) on Stack Overflow. For additional advanced search options, check out the [advanced search help](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know me was shorthand.

Comment: What if I want to find all my answers to questions that don't have accepted answers? I tried `user:me is:answer hasaccepted:no`, and it only showed my own questions. If I add `isaccepted:no` instead, it returns a list of my answers that weren't accepted, but includes answers from questions that *do have* some other accepted answer.

Comment: I like this, but this could / should be more obvious. Don't you think so? ;)

Comment: @Fabian: I agree. Or what would be useful is the ability to save such queries as templates in your user profile so you don't have to remember the syntax, just invoke them.

Answer (score 5):

Enter in the search:

```
user:<your user id> is:answer TVP
```

For example, my user id is 61305, so to search for "TVP" in my answers only:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A61305+TVP+is%3Aanswer

Your user id is 40521, so to search for "foo" in your answers only:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A40521+foo+is%3Aanswer

As for date range, doesn't look like it. They're not mentioned on the advanced search options, and [this question seems to imply the ninja stuff is missing date range queries too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options), but offers some potential workarounds.