# How to search answers to my questions?

Tags: support, search

I want to search through **the answers to** my questions. How can I do this?

For example:

```
votes:10 is:answer questionBy:me
```

I searched meta for this already, and found a ton of questions about searching my own *questions*, but not about searching *answers to* my quesitons.

Comment: This question is making my head spin. That, and the rum. Mostly the rum.

Comment: @AndrewBarber the unicorns should bring you back to reality

Comment: *Not* what you're asking, but for future reference: to search in *one* specific question, one can use [`inquestion:19478 unicorn`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A19478+unicorn) or [`inquestion:this unicorn`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3Athis+unicorn), once one knows in which question to search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search inside my own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140279/search-inside-my-own-answers)

Comment: @bad_coder This question is "the answers to my questions"; that one is "my own answers."  They are not duplicates.

Comment: @RyanM you're right, my mistake (reading through the tag got to me this time.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wrote a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions) that does this. You can search the body of answers given to your questions.
As the data explorer gets updated weekly, this is a workable solution till advanced search gets an update (**if**).

It can also handle upper and lower limits for vote count of answers.

**Update :**

Now also handles accepted status of answers!

**Update #2:**

Now question tags can also be searched!

**Update #3:**

Search within *your answers* to your questions! (that is, self answers or self-answered questions)