# Search by answers

Tags: support, answers, search

Maybe this topic has already been discussed here, but I couldn’t find an answer to it.

I remember having read answers which talked about a specific issue (which was not necessarily closely related  to the question), but I don’t know how to get to those answers.

Would it be possible to set up a way to make research for the expressions used in answers? Sort of like some dictionaries work. For instance, I am looking for answers where the expression “basic instinct” has been used. Could a search show me all answers where that expression has been used?

Comment: When asking a question, you would be suggested by the system about the questions which look similar/ or are relevant. If you still speculate, you can perform a google search and put site:____.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow if applicable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search inside my own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140279/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/282094 and other tricks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144955/282094

Answer (score 11):

Use one of the [advanced search operators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), `is:a` or `is:answer`. [Searching for is:a "basic instinct"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+%22basic+instinct%22) gives answers only:

[image]