# How do I search for posts before or after a certain date?

Tags: feature-request, search

I know I can view the [newest questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118286/list-questions-after-a-certain-date) and see the dates of questions/answers, but is there a way to search for questions within a specific date range? I've been trying to edit and clean up old questions, and so far, I'm stuck using the `page` parameter to jump to relatively old questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=1000&sort=newest and guessing as to the range.

This question has [come](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35349/187647) [up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122816/187647) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141371/187647), but the discussions and answers haven't seemed to reach a consensus. Is this feature not planned in the foreseeable future, are there technical limitations to it, or are there already search features that obviate the need for it?

EDIT: For possible syntax, I find something like this logical:

```
after:YYYY/MM/DD
after:YYYY
before:YYYY/MM/DD
before:YYYY
```

I like this syntax because a) it seems to mesh with existing syntax and b) it's simple to understand.  Personally, I'm familiar with this syntax because Gmail utilises a similar form, so any suggestions are welcome in case it only seems logical to Gmail users.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122816/187647) posited some ideas, but also raised the point (in my opinion, a minor one) that the syntax doesn't inform the user whether or not it's inclusive or exclusive. I have no opinion on that, so if this feature is implemented, it can probably be implemented based on whatever criteria someone sees fit.

Comment: No promises, but show me a syntax that's clean and makes sense...that's the biggest barrier, behind the scenes on our object model this already works (and is available via API v2)

Comment: @NickCraver Updated. Although *I* like the syntax I posted, whatever fits with the developers' criteria is ok with me.

Comment: I like this but in the mean time you can use data.se since you're looking for old questions. Here's a [quick query I wrote](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76202/old-python-questions?QuestionDate=1%2F1%2F2010). Obviously you can add additional output and criteria

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano - remember that created isn't the *only* date available though, so it would have to be more specific.  For example there's a creation date and a last activity date, both are used in many places on the site and we'd want the syntax to be able to search either, also how about times, do we just not allow more granularity than a day? (I'm asking...personally I'd be ok with that)  Also, probably `YYYY-MM-DD` if anything (since that's what we use to display everywhere that has those components)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter Thanks for the query; I'll be using that.
@NickCraver I didn't think of that. Would `createdafter`, `createdbefore`, `activeafter`, and `activebefore`, or some derivation of those, be too ambiguous (since there is overlap between them obviously)?

Comment: @NickCraver Also, I'd be fine with no more granularity than a day (even though it might be interesting to look at the quality of posts from around, say, 3 am). `-` as a delimiter is ok too. Either is logical to me.

Comment: This would be especially useful on meta, where I would like to check if anyone has raised a particular topic (e.g. change of font) within the previous week.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching by date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35348/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192699/282094