# Can we update the search tips to include all available operators?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

There are a couple of things missing from the ["advanced search tips"](https://stackoverflow.com/search):

- [Add date range to "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options)
- [Search just code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55473/search-just-code)

Can we update the tips, please?

Comment: I doubt that last one will work correctly now anyway, since they moved the message out of the post body.

Comment: @TimStone You're right, I'll remove it. Still, the message exists on duplicates that were closed before the message was removed, the hack is not completely useless.

Comment: Yeah, and a general hint that the negation operator will work like that would still be useful.

Comment: The date search stuff [has been implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), although it's still technically marked as experimental.

Comment: I wonder what a non-tech person is going to think of code searches on the non-tech sites. For example [code:"cup sugar"](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22cup+sugar%22) works fine and makes sense to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now [a help article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) that has all the supported operators, it will be linked from the bottom of the advanced search tips after the next build.

Comment: [It's missing `hasnotice`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193402/is-it-possible-to-search-for-posts-with-a-post-notice)

Comment: The `code:` operator isn't there. And there seems to be next to nothing for documentation on it anywhere.