# Advanced Search Tips should include search option hasnotice for (bounty) question

Tags: feature-request, search

I tried to search for new question with a bounty on stackoverflow and was stuck.

I was able to get the necessary search options by searching meta by post that contain "featured question search" and after clicking some possible duplicate links i got the necessary option `hasnotice`

Adding the search option `hasnotice` to the Advanced Search Tips makes it easier to find those questions.

Comment: Related: [Can we update the search tips to include all available operators?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166835/can-we-update-the-search-tips-to-include-all-available-operators)