# Is it possible to search for posts with a post notice?

Tags: support, search, post-notices

Is it possible to search for post which have a [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post), such as the "Insufficient Explanation" post notice?

This would be especially useful for moderators to be able to follow up on answers which have a post notice added to see if the issue driving the notice has been addressed yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `hasnotice:1` will produce any questions which currently have a lock or bounty notice attached to them as well as any answers which have any of the moderator post notices added to them.

Comment: Also it makes me very sad to see that so far *none* of the answers I have added post notices to have been improved :-(

Comment: @TheUnhandledException Time to ditch that label gun of yours and get out the flame thrower?

Comment: I believe so yes... :-/ Where did you find this by the way? It's not in the advanced search help that I could see and I searched meta before asking...

Comment: I most likely saw it in passing somewhere and just remembered it. I'm sure if you search for "hasnotice" here on Meta some stuff about it will come up.

Comment: [Ah ha, it's a question about bounties](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167250/advanced-search-tips-should-include-search-option-hasnotice-for-bounty-questio) and not about answer notices which is why I couldn't find it. Glad I asked this question!