# Highest voted questions in the last n days

Tags: support, search

How can I search for the highest voted questions that were asked in the last, say, 5 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search by `created` and sort by votes

```
created:2013-01-06..2013-01-11
```

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options) for more search options.