# How can I limit Stackoverlow to search for only recent answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, recent

I have a question about the Amazon API. This is a pretty common question, so when I search for it, there are already plenty of answers on SO. However, many of these answers are a year or two old -- based on the API before an important change. Now many of those answers are probably deprecated. I want to restrict to questions that will be relevant, which I can judge based on date.

So this leads to the question: I'd like to search for answers on StackOverflow, but I want to limit to only questions (or answers) that have been posted in the last, say, 1 year. Is there an easy way to do this that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post about it in [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122816/how-about-a-very-simple-date-filter-for-the-search) but it seems to imply that there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your search results by "newest". The most recent answers will be the first few pages. Unfortunately, there is no way to then take the first few pages of results and search just that set.